# SSRS - Have report execute sub-queries?

Tags: ssrs-2008, report, reporting, reporting-services

I've looked all over and cannot find an answer to my question; I can't even determine whether it is possible.

Referring to the attached image, you will notice that this is a statement report with data grouping activated.

1) The report shows all the services invoiced to an account by date.
   You can expand the group to see all the transactions that formed part of that service for        that day. (You can for instance make use of the same service multiple times per day)

2) This is the detailed layout of the service invoiced. This list is different for each service, but mainly it will show you a summarized transaction list (PK BatchId), which has the "+" symbol next to it to enable drilldown to a detailed report of the batch.

**My problem:** 
When loading the statement report, we are now hitting multiple tables, multiple times to produce the data to be grouped and displayed in #2 (refer to image).

We are trying to avoid this like the plague.

**My Question** 
Is there a way to populate #2 when and only when the user clicks a "+" symbol or an "expand" image where the "+" is currently located in #1.

In other words. We dispose of the group function and populate the statement without detailed information. When the user clicks on #1, we load a sproc, populate a dataset and display the data in #2.

Any thoughts on this?

[image: Statement report]

Comment: I like your question! I've not done it before but maybe combination of report variables and user function to set them could do this? Also does a matrix table work?

Answer (score 1):

[Drillthrough Reports](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff519554.aspx) look like a good solution here. See the link for more information on how these work. So basically you have the report without the detailed information, but when somebody clicks on 1 it opens up a new report with the details behind it.

Comment: Hi @Tom Jenkin.
We are currently using Drillthrough reports in the statement, but management wants to reduce rendering time (Internet connection in my country is not the fastest ever), so now they basically want to "combine" the main statement report and the drillthrough report. Since this is a statement, the drillthrough report is determined by the service displayed in the statement line, i.e. there are about 20 reports linked to it.

Answer (score 1):

After testing, I confirmed that subreports are executed even if they are hidden within an element that can be toggled.

So subreports won't answer this problem.

[Edited: previously I thought they could be used. JAT points out that this negative answer may have some value, so I'm leaving it.]

Comment: That would be great @Jamie F.
I would really appreciate if you could share your results.

Comment: Fail! I didn't recall correctly. All subreports in a report do seem to get called, even if hidden. I will be deleting this answer soon, but I'll leave it up for a day, just to share these results.

Comment: Well, actually you did answer the question. It cannot be done.
Thank you very much for running this test @Jamie F